# Grouping by a variable length substring in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query where I need to group by the substring of a variable length string. The string is a path in a URL. For example, the following should be grouped together...

1. /health/pushups/
2. /health/pushups/1
3. /health/pushups/1/
4. health/pushups/1
5. health/pushups
6. health/pushups/1/

Where 1 can be any integer up to 30. I would like all of those to roll up into /health/pushups/ in a GROUP BY function.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . .  This is tricky because of the `/` at the beginning.  This should work:

```
select (case when url like '/%'
             then substring_index(url, '/', 3)
             else concat('/', substring_index_url, '/', 2))
        end) as grp,
       count(*)
from t
group by grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

`WHERE ( url LIKE '%health%' and url LIKE '%pushups%' )`

or with [REGEXP_LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-syntax)

`WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(url,'^+health/pushups')>0`

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, I need it to be a wildcard match for othre pages.

Comment: `'^+health/pushups'` can also be a variable, depending on which pages you want?